# How to connect multi-effects processor to guitar amp?

Tags: guitar, amplifiers, guitar-effects, effects-pedal, effects

My guitar amp: Line 6 Spider IV 15

My effects pedal: Zoom GFX8

I want to know how should I keep the settings of my amp(which channel and eq settings of this amp) when I connect this multi-effects processor.

And also please verify my connection is right below. Connection goes from guitar to effects processor in and from effects processor L/mono out to the input of the guitar amp.

Thanks

Comment: Your connection is right. However, sometimes, you'd want to go via the effects send and return. Look some information up on that matter, you'll understand.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting your way will include any settings that you have on the pre-amp section on your amp. Tone controls, or any other. If you set everything flat it will (should) not affect anything going in. Move anything, and you have a secondary set of parameters.

Plug into the amplifier section of the amp and you'll by-pass all that, and go straight into the power amp, using the pedalboard *as* the pre-amp. There may even be a different socket on the 'board for each scenario.

EDIT: it appears you only have guitar in, not send/return. So you're stuck with using one channel or the other. clean is probably better if you want to use the effects in the Zoom. If the dirty channel has a good distortion mode, then plug into that and use other effects on the Zoom. You could try minimal distortion on one, some on the other for a different overdrive.

Comment: If I use above way of connection with amp settings to flat, would it work fine. I don’t need any changes to the tone coming out of my pedal.

Comment: That's the usual state of affairs. You need to try out *all* of your options. There will be some that you just don't like, but you may well find others by accident that you think are great. Nothing's going to break.

Answer (score 1):

On that amp, you can also connect the mono output of the effects board to the “mp3” or aux input of the amp. This will bypass the amp’s preamp section and go straight to the power amp and speaker. That will allow the effects board to do all the amp and speaker modelling with minimal colouration from the guitar amp.

Answer (score 0):

There are two routes you could connect the Zoom unit to your amp:

-The method you describe is quite correct. You simply run the mono output of the Zoom effects unit into the instrument input of your amp.

-The second method would be to insert the Zoom unit into the effects loop of your amp.

The second method makes more sense if you are using delay or reverb effects, depending on what amp you are using. If you are using a tube amp with some overdrive then you would be stacking reverb and delay effects before the overdrive in scenario 1, above.

Conversely distortion and fuzz effects tend not to sound their best when placed in the effects loop of an amp as, to some degree, these effects are designed to push the preamp stage of an amplifier.

Comment: My amp doesn’t have such inputs. It has only guitar in and phone out.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is right!
your amp will affect the tone even if you keep all the EQ to 0, if you want to completely bypass your amp and use your amp only as a speaker you need to have an adapter and then connect the cable to aux/mp3 input in your amp, and not in the usual Input.
however, it is not really necessary, just don't have a distortion preamp on your effect pedal along with distortion on your amp... 
I would suggest you plug the guitar to the amp without the effect pedal first and configure a good sounding clean channel and then plug the effect pedal and have fun ;)

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, you can bypass on spider iv by pressing the tap button and holding it and then switching on the amp. I have a spider iv that I am connecting to a GT8, but I am having trouble getting the tone right. I thought I would bypass the amp and use the processor for preamp. I am not getting a good tone somehow

Comment: I tried connecting to my creative pc speakers. It sounds way better than spider

Comment: Yeah somehow spider isn't sounding very good. I wonder why. There must be a solution to this?